# how to run a continuous loop and add input to text

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, constants

I have to run a continuous loop, until the user decides otherwise, which will add the input entered  into a text file but i can't seem to get the while loop working properly.

this is what i have so far:

```
def main():

    #Open a file named names.txt.
    outfile = open('names.txt', 'w')

    #user enters input
    fname = input("Enter first name:\t")
    lname = input("Enter second name:\t")
    telephone = input("Enter telephone number:\t")
    print("")
    continues = input("Continue? (y = yes):\t")
    input_list = [fname, lname, telephone, continues]

    outfile.write(fname)
    outfile.write(lname)
    outfile.write(telephone)

    outfile.close()

    while continues == 0:
        if continues == "y":
            fname = input("Enter first name:\t")
            lname = input("Enter second name:\t")
            telephone = input("Enter telephone number:\t")
            print("")
            continues = input("Continue?:\t")

            outfile.write(fname)
            outfile.write(lname)
            outfile.write(telephone)

            outfile.close()
        else:
            print("File Written")

#call main
main()
```

could someone help me out please, i'm using python 3.3.2

Comment: You might get better answers by giving only relevant parts of your code.

Comment: `while continues == 0:` - when would `continues` ever be 0? Under what conditions is this loop supposed to carry on?

Comment: i dont know i just did that as an example i had while continues == y and it kept saying y wasnt defined...

Comment: `y` and `"y"` are not the same. The first is the variable named `y` (which is undefined), the second is a string containing the character `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better wrapping the whole thing in the loop:

**Ex:**

```
def main():

    while True: 

        fname = input("Enter first name:\t")
        lname = input("Enter second name:\t")
        telephone = input("Enter telephone number:\t")
        print ("")
        continues = input("Continue? (y = yes):\t").lower() # y to break the loop
        input_list = [fname, lname, telephone, continues]

        if continues == 'y':
            with open('names.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                # write things to outfile. 
                # The with block auto closes 
                # the file after it's statements
            print ('File Written')
            break # this is how you exit the loop
```

**EDIT:**

maybe this line would make more sense:

```
continues = input("Write to File? (y = yes):\t").lower()
```

Comment: thank you so much only thing is "y" is suppose to make the loop continue not break it, but thank you :)

Comment: glad I could help. As you probably see, it's easy to tailor that part of it to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop that is working. Can you try it and adapt it to your case?

```
run = None    
while run != 'n':
   run = raw_input('continue? [y/n]').lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, just try :

```
continues='y'
while 1:
    if continues == "y":
        fname = input("Enter first name:\t")
        lname = input("Enter second name:\t")
        telephone = input("Enter telephone number:\t")
        print("")
        continues = input("Continue?:\t")

        outfile.write(fname)
        outfile.write(lname)
        outfile.write(telephone)

        outfile.close()
    else:
        print("File Written")
        break
```